# Mongoose - using Populate on an array of ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a schema that looks a bit like:

```
var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    recipients: { type: [Schema.ObjectId], ref: 'User' },
    messages: [ conversationMessageSchema ]
});
```

So my recipients collection, is a collection of object id's referencing my user schema / collection.

I need to populate these on query, so i'm trying this:

```
Conversation.findOne({ _id: myConversationId})
.populate('user')
.run(function(err, conversation){
    //do stuff
});
```

But obviously 'user' isn't populating...

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the name of the schema path instead of the collection name:

```
Conversation.findOne({ _id: myConversationId})
.populate('recipients') // <==
.exec(function(err, conversation){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: my mongoose v5.11.14

Answer (score 125):

For anyone else coming across this question.. the OP's code has an error in the schema definition.. it should be:

```
var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    recipients: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    messages: [ conversationMessageSchema ]
});
mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);
```

Comment: You sir just saved me a world of pain. *tips hat*

Comment: Good way ! but how can you do an array of unique object id? With no duplicate?

Comment: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' , unique: true }

Comment: @MuliYulzary, I don't think that's right based on the docs right [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator). They claim it's `not` a validator but only helps in the creation of `MongoDB` indexes.

Comment: not working. returning empty array. my mongoose v5.11.14