# Indexing array of references using mongodb multikey indexing method in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema has an array of ObjectIds which are refs to another schema. What i want is to index this array entry using multikey indexing method of mongodb. 
So that given an **ObjectId** of some document in the **ProductCat** Collection, i can list all the documents in my current collection which has the given **ObjectId** in the **_pro_cat** field.

I am confused about the exact way in which i should declare the field, in mongoose schema declaration, Here is what i am trying:

```
_pro_cat: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'ProductCat', index: true }

_pro_cat: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductCat', index: true }]
```

The name of this collection is Seller. I am making the relation, by using the reference in the schema and the actual field value is an array, each of type ObjectId, which will be the ObjectIds of the documents in the other Collection (ProductCat in this case). If i index this field i.e.. _pro_cat, then given an ObjectId of a document in ProductCat Collection, i would be able to find all the documents in the Seller collection which has given ObjectId in its array field _pro_cat.

I think i may have to call a separate index function. But i thought that this is a field level indexing so it may not be needed.

I suspect the later is only for sub-docs and not for refs. Would greatly appreciate, if anyone could shed some light on it. Thanks.

**Side Question: [RE-SOLVED]**
In the mongodb documentation, it says that multikey indexing is automatic. [multikey indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/). Does this mean that if that field is indexed, using the above methods, then mongo will recognize that the field is an array and use multikey indexing. OR does it mean that all the fields which are of array type will get indexed, without the need to explicitly telling it to index.

Thanks a lot.

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568281/mongoose-using-populate-on-an-array-of-objectid/)

Comment: Wait do you mean that you expect a server-side relation to exist between the two collections because you indexed the multivalue field?

Comment: @Sammaye The name of this collection is **Seller**. I am making the relation, by using the reference in the schema and the actual field value is an array, each of type ObjectId, which will be the ObjectIds of the documents in the other Collection (**ProductCat** in this case). If i index this field i.e.. **_pro_cat**, then given an ObjectId of a document in **ProductCat** Collection, i would be able to find all the documents in the **Seller** collection which has given ObjectId in its array field **_pro_cat**.

Comment: I am looking for the right syntax to declare this indexing to happen in the Schema, or the right Function call after the Schema is defined. I have updated the Question for more details, please check again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multikey Indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) **means** that every item in an array-field is indexed if you tell mongo to index the field.

It **does not mean** that all array fields are indexed automatically without the need to explicitely tell mongo to index the field.

Comment: Thanks @heinob for clearing that up. I am sorry i wasn't clear about my primary Question, Please see the updated Question, and the comment on the Question, in reply to Sammaye. Thanks.