# Mongoose, query a collection with a set of ObjectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating an api with node.js, express and mongoose. I'm pretty new to mongosse and I am wondering if there exists a better way to do what I want.

I have two collections: users and expenses.

User example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c4bc6a39d9992d6407427e"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "name" : "JohnD",
    "password" : "xxxxx",
    "__v" : 26,
    "budget" : 400,
    "saving" : 300,
    "wage" : 1340,
    "expenses" : [
            ObjectId("59cd076544fa3e64ec32c7e3"),
            ObjectId("59cd07f0ed7bd2192cab72bd"),
            ObjectId("59cd0a78e19060451059dce7"),
            ObjectId("59cd0b24e19060451059dce8"),
            ObjectId("59cd0b8fe19060451059dce9"),
            ObjectId("59cdf34be19060451059dcf4"),
            ObjectId("59cdf3c1e19060451059dcf5"),
            ObjectId("59cdf417e19060451059dcf6"),
            ObjectId("59cdf446e19060451059dcf7"),
            ObjectId("59cdf46ee19060451059dcf8"),
            ObjectId("59cdf4bce19060451059dcf9"),
            ObjectId("59cdf6dee19060451059dcfa"),
            ObjectId("59cdf6f5e19060451059dcfb"),
            ObjectId("59cdf768e19060451059dcfc"),
            ObjectId("59cdf798e19060451059dcfd"),
            ObjectId("59cdf806e19060451059dcfe")
     ]
}
```

Expense example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59cd07f0ed7bd2192cab72bd"),
    "name" : "shopping",
    "price" : 100,
    "date" : 1506607687013,
    "repetition" : 0,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59cd0a78e19060451059dce7"),
    "name" : "gazoil",
    "price" : 50,
    "date" : 1506607687013,
    "repetition" : 0,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to do a function which takes a user and return all of its expenses. Am I forced to loop through all objectId in user.expenses or there is a proper way to do that directly with mongoose ?

Comment: Depends on how you defined your schemas. If you use refs then  you can use populate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568281/mongoose-using-populate-on-an-array-of-objectid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose has a method for doing what you are willing to do: [Query Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

You need to set your schema right and **push the refs to the children**, then use the `populate()` method:

```
const user = await User
  .findOne({ _id: 'yourObjId' })
  .populate('expenses')
  .exec()

console.log(user.stories)
```

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $lookup/[aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Aggregate)

Check some examples on this answer which seem to explain your use case.

[Mongodb, aggregate query with $lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912466/280842)