# Try to populate in mongoose and it doesn't work (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i Make mini cart with Product and user Auth, Evereting work perfect but whan i try to make a route that pickup all the product from the user and view them in specific page and it not work for me.
it returns the user but not the product.

UserSchema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "product"
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  data: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

ProductScheama

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    quantity:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    data:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

module.exports=Product=mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema)
```

I am trying to create a function that gives me the name, price and description of the product and it fails.
my router:

```js
router.get("/products/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let pro = await User.find({ product: req.params.id }).populate("product", [
      "name",
      "price",
      "description"
    ]);
    if (!pro) {
      return res.json({ msg: "This user not have products to show" });
    }
    res.json(pro);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server errors");
  }
});
```

result from Postman:

```js
[
    {
        "product": [],
        "_id": "5d5bfb96963ca600ec412bca",
        "name": "Anonny Annon",
        "email": "Annony@gmail.com",
        "address": "Israel",
        "password": "$2a$10$gESTIaBVifzhRDR2zOKsw.Q79gCT07IK2VnDoyT2oU5htqfBuAj8W",
        "data": "2019-08-20T13:54:30.267Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `product` should be defined this way :

```
product: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "product"
}]
```

instead of `type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]`

Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568281/mongoose-using-populate-on-an-array-of-objectid)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Thile, Work Perfect.