# Use MongoDB, MaxMind database and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, maxmind

I've imported http://www.maxmind.com/en/city (GeoIP City) into MongoDB. There are two collections: blocks and location.

Blocks have start of ip range and end of an ip range and an integer (will make this a MongoID later) indicating a document in the location collection.

ip addresses in are stored as NumberLong in the blocks collection.

I get an ip address and convert it into long with the php function iptolong (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php), giving me a value like 3758096128

Now I need to make a query that get me the id from the correct document in the blocks collection and then look up the location in the location collection (with the help of the id)

I can obvious make two queries, but this is not very efficient.

My first step would be something like (in PHP):

```
$query = array(
    'startIpNum' => array('$gte' => $ipLong),
    'endIpNum' => array('$lte' => $ipLong),
    );
```

(Still figuring out why above query does not return any data)

But what would be the next step in the process in getting data from two collections?

Comment: You need to do a JOIN query on the collection. Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4588699/2332336

Comment: Thanks you might be right! Any idea why above statement does not return any data? What I am trying to do is (in SQL)

SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE startIpNum => $ipLong AND endIpNum <= $ipLong;

Comment: Try the same query from the MongoDb console for you database and collection. What are the results?

Comment: I read a bit more about the query and it seems I need to be using $and

    $query = array(
 '$and' =>
  array(
      'startIpNum' => array('$gte' => $ipLong),
      'endIpNum' => array('$lte' => $ipLong),
     )
    );

Which gives me an error: $or requires nonempty array

Had this before with $set because it was between double quotes, bit replacing them with one quote does not do the trick here. Any suggestions?